# geom_sf: scale_*_continuous has no effect

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

The following use of `scale_x_continuous` in combination with `geom_sf` removes the x-axis labels completely.
I assume that the specified breaks do not really exist in the ggplot object and subsequently none at all are shown.

Is this caused by the automatic transformation from EPSG 32717 to EPSG 4326 by `coord_sf()`?

```r
data(ecuador, package = "sperrorest")
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.5.1, GDAL 2.2.2, proj.4 4.9.2
library(ggplot2)
data = st_as_sf(ecuador, coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 32717)
ggplot(data) + 
  geom_sf()
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(data) + 
  geom_sf() + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(79.085, 79.055))
```

[image]

```r
devtools::session_info()
#> Session info -------------------------------------------------------------
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
#>  system   x86_64, linux-gnu           
#>  ui       X11                         
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  en_US.UTF-8                 
#>  tz       Europe/Berlin               
#>  date     2018-01-29
#> Packages -----------------------------------------------------------------
#>  package    * version    date       source                            
#>  backports    1.1.2      2017-12-13 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
#>  base       * 3.4.3      2017-12-01 local                             
#>  class        7.3-14     2015-08-30 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                    
#>  classInt     0.1-24     2017-04-16 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
#>  colorspace   1.3-2      2016-12-14 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
#>  compiler     3.4.3      2017-12-01 local                             
#>  datasets   * 3.4.3      2017-12-01 local                             
#>  DBI          0.7        2017-06-18 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
#>  devtools     1.13.4     2017-11-09 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
#>  digest       0.6.15     2018-01-28 cran (@0.6.15)                    
#>  e1071        1.6-8      2017-02-02 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
#>  evaluate     0.10.1     2017-06-24 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
#>  ggplot2    * 2.2.1.9000 2018-01-29 Github (tidyverse/ggplot2@401511e)
#>  graphics   * 3.4.3      2017-12-01 local                             
#>  grDevices  * 3.4.3      2017-12-01 local                             
#>  grid         3.4.3      2017-12-01 local                             
#>  gtable       0.2.0      2016-02-26 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
#>  htmltools    0.3.6      2017-04-28 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
#>  knitr        1.19       2018-01-29 cran (@1.19)                      
#>  lazyeval     0.2.1      2017-10-29 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
#>  magrittr     1.5        2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
#>  memoise      1.1.0      2017-04-21 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
#>  methods    * 3.4.3      2017-12-01 local                             
#>  munsell      0.4.3      2016-02-13 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
#>  pillar       1.1.0      2018-01-14 cran (@1.1.0)                     
#>  plyr         1.8.4      2016-06-08 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
#>  Rcpp         0.12.15    2018-01-20 cran (@0.12.15)                   
#>  rlang        0.1.6.9003 2018-01-29 Github (tidyverse/rlang@a8c15c6)  
#>  rmarkdown    1.8        2017-11-17 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
#>  rprojroot    1.3-2      2018-01-03 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
#>  scales       0.5.0.9000 2018-01-29 Github (hadley/scales@d767915)    
#>  sf         * 0.6-0      2018-01-06 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
#>  stats      * 3.4.3      2017-12-01 local                             
#>  stringi      1.1.6      2017-11-17 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
#>  stringr      1.2.0      2017-02-18 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
#>  tibble       1.4.2      2018-01-22 cran (@1.4.2)                     
#>  tools        3.4.3      2017-12-01 local                             
#>  udunits2     0.13       2016-11-17 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
#>  units        0.5-1      2018-01-08 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
#>  utils      * 3.4.3      2017-12-01 local                             
#>  withr        2.1.1.9000 2018-01-29 Github (jimhester/withr@df18523)  
#>  yaml         2.1.16     2017-12-12 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
```

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: The [ggplot2 documentation](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_continuous.html) shows how to manually set axis breaks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your breaks must be negative because you are in the Western hemisphere :

```
ggplot(data) + 
    geom_sf() + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(-79.085, -79.055))
```

[image]

It is also easy to change the crs directly from ggplot with `coord_sf` :

```
ggplot(data) + 
    geom_sf() + 
    coord_sf(datum = st_crs(data)) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(712500, 715500))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, thanks. Also just found out that the main problem was that I need to supply negative values for both scales because of the hemispheres.